# How to write below sql query using Django queryset?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have tried many solutions but could not find any luck, and also is django queryset faster  than the raw sql join queries?

```
Models -

class S2BotCategoriesMappings(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    id_s2_bot = models.ForeignKey(S2Bot, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_s2_bot', blank=True, null=True)
    id_s2_bot_categories = models.ForeignKey(S2BotCategories, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_s2_bot_categories', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 's2_bot_categories_mappings'


class S2UserSubscription(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    id_s2_users = models.ForeignKey('S2Users', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_s2_users', blank=True, null=True)
    id_s2_bot = models.ForeignKey(S2Bot, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_s2_bot', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 's2_user_subscription'
```

```
query = """
            SELECT
               s2_user_subscription.id_s2_users,
               s2_user_subscription.id_s2_bot,
               s2_bot_categories_mappings.id_s2_bot_categories
            FROM  s2_user_subscription
            LEFT JOIN s2_bot_categories_mappings 
            ON s2_user_subscription.id_s2_bot = s2_bot_categories_mappings.id_s2_bot;
        """
```

Answer (score 0):

This link has the answer to the first question you asked [Django QuerySet vs. raw SQL performance considerations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44329757/django-queryset-vs-raw-sql-performance-considerations)

I found this from the documentation. It should have the answer you seek. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/sql/ More specifically the link below has answer how to map query fields to model fields in Django because I understood that is what you are trying to do.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/sql/#mapping-query-fields-to-model-fields. I hope this helps.